# MVVM and WPF structure

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been recently trying to re-write a WinForm application to WPF. I've been trying to implement an MVVM structure into my application because it's starting to look a lot like Winforms where I need to name my controls `x:Name` and referencing them all the time. Essentially, I'm not using the power of what MVVM provides.

One thing I'm having trouble wrapping my head around, is the `Window`. Every time I create a Window, it generates a partial class. My question is, how does that tie in to MVVM? The confusion starts as to what content this class should contain. Does it have a single `DataContext` binding? What about button events?

From my understanding (at the moment), is that this "partial" class should have very minimal code, perhaps only to bind your `ViewModel` in your constructor:

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

and the rest of the functionality should come from your `ViewModel` with the help of binding things on  `XAML`. However, each `ViewModel` should be tied to a single `Model`. But what happens when this particular Window calls for many Models, such as a Client, Products, etc? Do you make a single `ViewModel` class that somehow does everything?

The essence of my question lies within the contents of this particual "partial" class and its relation to the `ViewModel`.

Comment: UI logic goes in the codebehind, business logic goes in your view models.  Your bindings and DataTemplates will take care of most of the UI juggling that you had to do in winforms, but if you create custom controls, you'll be adding any code they need to function into their codebehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've got two questions:

1. How the heck does this partial class thing fit in with MVVM?
2. How do I structure all the view models and models and stuff?

1) What you are referring to as a "partial class" is often called "code-behind" when discussing WPF. This is because in that in non MVVM patterns it usually has all the actual C# code that sits behind the xaml layout - i.e. "code-behind".

You're correct that a good indication of a good MVVM implementation is minimal/no code-behind. As you mentioned, usually all it will have is binding the DataContext to the ViewModel - and in lots of frameworks this is all handled for you and you don't even need that. In my MVVM projects every partial class looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Views
{
    public partial class GeneratorView : CreatableView
    {
        public GeneratorView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the nice thing with MVVM is that all the spaghetti event updating/connection code that you had to have in WinForms is all bypassed by using bindings. But as you noted, you can still do this with WPF but it's generally considered bad practice, and definitely with MVVM.

With all content and commands being bound directly to the ViewModel through data binding, the partial class need not have any content at all. There's lots of interpretations, but on a basic level:

- The View lays things out and shows things on the screen.
- The View Model contains UI specific data and logic. It deals with commands from the view, and may utilize business services.
- The Model represents your data. Think of the stuff that's going in a database or file system.

2) MVVM is not strict in how you structure it. Generally the convention is you have ViewModel for every View. However, I believe it's fine to have a ViewModel without a View. Especially simple ones.

> But what happens when this particular Window calls for many Models, such as a Client, Products, etc? Do you make a single ViewModel class that somehow does everything?

Not at all, it seems like you've got this all-or-nothing monolithic ViewModel in your head. If these were really simple structures, I'd do it like this:

[image]

However, you might want a dedicated ClientView or ProductView, and instead embed them in the main view:

[image]

The key thing is your ViewModels may contains other ViewModels, arrays of ViewModels. Similarly, your View can embed other View's to display it's ViewModels - or not. If they're simple, or you're just, say, listing a few properties (Maybe when you click an 'info' button a dialog shows up and that has the full View for said ViewModel, but in the list you just want the Name and Cost.

It's flexible. On thing is, often the Window isn't even part of the MVVM pattern. It's so "dumb" that it doesn't even have a ViewModel (also, what if you want to embed your app into another app or something?).

It's more flexible to have a high-level "AppViewModel" and all your Window does is contain that (often not even bothering with a WindowViewModel, it's not really a concern).

Comment: Nicely written and concise! The second picture described my issue: a ViewModel containing other view models. However, what if the WindowViewModel had other viewmodels in it, say six? Shouldn't there be a way to create dependency injection in your WindowViewModel?

Comment: Are these six View-ViewModels displayed at the same time? Do you expect them to change? In my application I have a central ViewModel that contains navagation (forwards, back, parent page, list of child pages etc) and manages their display. Incidentally I do inject it into pages as a "PageController" that has the method "DisplayPage(BasePageViewModel page)". That kind of high-level application/display structure is all done using IBasePageViewModels. The pages themselves are so specific that you can't really inject their content (unless they just bunched up a load of views).

Comment: Really that kind of stuff is beyond just MVVM, and just wider application design. Dependency Injection is about injecting Services. Child ViewModels aren't really services and shouldn't be injected using DI in my opinion, unless they're performing a service - but even then it should probably be extracted from the ViewModel ideally.

Comment: Well six was perhaps a hypothetical number. Right now, I have MainWindow which is bound to MainViewModel in its DataContext. In MainViewModel I have two ViewModels which are injected in the Constructor right away. My curiosity rose when I'd need more control over a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more than one model in a view model. The aim of the view model is to abstract from the business layer (models, services).

For creating and keeping the instances you may use IoC (Inversion of Control) containers. There are many IoC containers available to use in .NET applications such as Castle Windsor, Autofac and so on (see [List of .NET Dependency Injection Containers (IOC)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)). You just need to instantiate a view model object by necessary model objects, for example like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IClientModel _clientModel;
    private readonly IProductModel _productModel;

    public ViewModel(IClientModel clientModel, IProductModel productModel)
    {
        _clientModel = clientModel;
        _productModel = productModel;
    }

    // Logic of your view model
}
```

Also you need to configure object dependencies and scopes (your model will be a singleton or a new instance of the type). The container injects dependencies when it creates the objects.

Also I recommend to read the article [MVVM - IOC Containers and MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx).

Comment: Okay, I guess the main question here: what is a view in this case? If I have a window, is that considered a view? I have a few things in this window, labels, textboxes, that are completely unrelated to each other: would they be considered a "view" ?

Comment: View is xaml file. It may be window, component and so on. The view model provides data via binding to the appropriate labels, textboxes and other controls of your view.

Comment: I see. So in my main window (with my MainViewModel), I can have multiple view instances (like you've shown) and simply bind them to their appropriate DataContext ?

Comment: Yes, you can bind ```MainViewModel``` instance to the appropriate ```DataContext``` of each view instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the way I approach it anyway, is to keep my Window dumb.  How dumb?  I guess it depends on the application.  If I am just trying to throw a proof of concept or something with low importance together then I will cut a few corners.  If I am working an a large application that will need to be maintained then I am going to be more strict, I may even frown on setting the ViewModel from the constructor in that case.

> However, each ViewModel should be tied to a single Model

I don't know that I agree with that.  That is not how I have approached MVVM, anyway.  I would say that every *View should be tied to a ViewModel*.  Within the ViewModel it may be the case that you are only dealing with one model but I have also had great success using a single ViewModel to expose multiple models to a View in a coherent way as well.

Here is an example of a template I use as a jumping off point in some of my smaller projects.  I like to use explicit `ViewModel` properties in my Window and Views but you don't have to; you could modify this to use the `DataContext` property instead.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object ViewModel
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ViewModel",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

In the code behind the `ViewModel` propoerty is just a dependency property of the Window.  I will bind the Window content to this property.  In this case it is an `object` but it could be some base ViewModel class or an interface if you want.

In my Window's markup I add a DataTemplate for each ViewModel to the Window's resources.  If everything is wired together correctly WPF's implicit data templating will take over and make sure the correct view is rendered whenever the `ViewModel` property is changed.

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Example.ViewModels;assembly=Example"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Example.Views;assembly=Example">

   <Window.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FirstViewModel}">
            <views:FirstView ViewModel="{Binding }" />
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SecondViewModel}">
            <views:SecondView ViewModel="{Binding }" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Window.Resources>

   <Grid>
      <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Content="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What about a ViewModel that exposes multiple ViewModels? Say there's a window where you'd bind MainViewModel. Say also that there are different sections of this window with different views that require their own ViewModels. Is it okay to hold multiple viewmodels in the MainViewModel and doing something like this:

`<Label Content="{Binding Path=FirstViewModel.Timer}" />
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SecondViewModel.Timer}" />`